# PFQuery never has cached results

Tags: caching, parse-platform, pfquery

I run this code to fetch results using Parse.com's `PFQuery`:

```
+ (void)fetchFresh:(BOOL)refresh threadsForUser:(PFUser *)user orItem:(PFObject *)item withCompletion:(void(^)(NSArray *array))completion {

    PFQuery *queryFrom = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:THREAD];
    [queryFrom whereKey:THREAD_FROM equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    PFQuery *queryTo = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:THREAD];
    [queryTo whereKey:THREAD_TO equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

    if (user) {
        [queryFrom whereKey:THREAD_TO equalTo:user];
        [queryTo whereKey:THREAD_FROM equalTo:user];
    }

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[queryFrom, queryTo]];
    [query includeKey:THREAD_FROM];
    [query includeKey:THREAD_TO];
    [query includeKey:THREAD_ITEM];
    [query includeKey:@"item.owner"];
    [query includeKey:@"item.purpose"];
    [query includeKey:@"item.category"];
    [query includeKey:@"item.shareContacts"];
    [query includeKey:@"item.shareGroups"];
    [query includeKey:THREAD_MESSAGES];
    [query includeKey:THREAD_SWAP_ITEMS];
    [query includeKey:@"swapItems.owner"];
    [query includeKey:@"swapItems.purpose"];
    [query includeKey:@"swapItems.category"];
    [query includeKey:@"swapItems.shareContacts"];
    [query includeKey:@"swapItems.shareGroups"];

    if (item) {
        [query whereKey:THREAD_ITEM equalTo:item];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@ %@", refresh ? @"REFRESH" : @"NO REFRESH", query.hasCachedResult ? @"CACHE" : @"NO CACHE");
    [query setCachePolicy:(refresh || !query.hasCachedResult) ? kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork: kPFCachePolicyCacheElseNetwork];
    query.limit = 1000;

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock...];
}
```

The idea here is that it should turn to cache if there are cached results, but fetch them the first time when there are none.

When I try to `NSLog` if the `query` has cached results, the result is always `NO`.

It's worth mentioning that I run this exact code every time, i.e. I create a new `PFQuery` object every time. My understanding is that results are cached based on the collection of `PFQuery` properties as opposed to it being the same object, so I would expect the results to be cached.

**ALSO**, the method is a class method in a utility class that I use to process my data requests. Can this be an issue?

Comment: I thought the `hasCachedResults` is not updated until you actually run the query, and that it's meant to be an indication of where the results came from? Any reason you're avoiding LDS?

Comment: @artooras Based on the code that you shared, that is nothing in there that would prevent caching. So the problem apparently lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I have updated my question to provide the full method with context. So, the query is a composite `orQuery`, and it is generated in a class method. Any ideas?

Comment: @lightice11, you are right, but I'm expecting to see cached results the second time I run the same query.